# {{action}} with a click event doesn't trigger the function in the v2 Ember router

Tags: ember.js

I just updated Ember and I am trying to convert an old app to the new router API.

In my template I have this:

```
<button {{ action "createNewApp" }} class="btn btn-primary">Create application</button>
```

And I put a createNewApp in my route:

```
App.CreateAppRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplates: function() {
        this.render({ outlet: 'content'});
    },
    createNewApp: function(){
        console.log("It's clicked");
    }
});
```

However, when I click on the button the function is never called. I have tried to change the target of the event to the controller but it's still not working. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to handle the click using a function in the events property of the router (thanks sly7_7) or using a function in the controller:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Content Here:</h1>
    {{outlet content}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="content-view">
    <h2>content</h2>
    <button {{ action "createNewApp" }} class="btn btn-primary">Create application</button>
  </script>
```

JS:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.CreateAppView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "content-view"    
});
App.CreateAppController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    createNewApp: function(){
        console.log("It's clicked, controller");
    }
});

App.Router.map(function(match) {
  match('/').to('createApp');
});
App.CreateAppRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplates: function() {
        this.render({ outlet: 'content'});
    },
    events: {
        createNewApp: function(){
            console.log("It's clicked, router");
        }
    }
});
```

When the button is clicked, the console log message is `"It's clicked, controller"` and when the function in the controller is removed the action is handled by the router, and the console log message is `"It's clicked, router"`.  If no target is specified in the `{{action}}` Ember tries to find the event in the view, then the controller, then the route.

This is using a build of emberjs built today from source.

*Original answer below:*

The `{{action}}` in the new router is replaced with `{{linkTo}}`.

The emberjs.com guides are constantly being updated with new info about the new router.  The [links](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) guide covers the `{{linkTo}}` helper, and the [actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) guide discusses using the `{{action}}` helper to handle events in templates.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this. When you said `{{action}}` is being  replaced, what exactly do you mean? Where can I read more about this? And why would the `{{action}}` helper be available if it's being replaced?

Comment: I have checked the docs and I am using linkTo in other parts of my code. But when I read the docs I got the impression that you use linkTo when you want to transition to a state and action is used to bind events (such as click). Isn't that why they are in different parts in the docs? Or are you saying that linkTo can substitute action and the action part will be deleted in the future?

Comment: This comes directly from the docs:

1) LINKS:
You create a link to a route using the {{linkTo}} helper.

2) ACTION:
You may want to trigger high level events in response to a simple user event (like a click).

They are obviously different things and I cannot see how linkTo can replace action. It seems more like an addition!

Comment: Ahh, yes you are right, I thought you were talking about only transitioning states.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm doing. I don't get it. The weird things is that I tried to explicitly set the target for the event to controller and it still didn't work. When I changed the target to the view it worked!!! But this is not good since I don't want my view to handle requests to my server

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous I believe with no target specified, the `{{action}}` will default to the view, and if it is not found try the controller.  Did your action helper look like this: `{{action target="controller"}}`? Does it work without a target?  Also, are you sure your names match with what the router is expecting?  With the name `CreateAppRoute` the router will use `CreateAppController` as the controller and `CreateAppView` as the view if they exist.

Comment: Yes, I am sure the names match the expected ones. Yes, I tried target="controller" but it didn't call the controller function. Without a target it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you miss just something, to declare the events in the `events` property map of the related route. something like App.CreateAppRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ renderTemplates: function(){...}, events: {createNewApp: function(){
        console.log("It's clicked, router");
    }}

Comment: That works! I hadn't seen the `events` property.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Yup, that works. Where is this events property mentioned in the docs?

Comment: How can I get the controller in the context of that event?