# Ember - controller actions not found from view

Tags: ember.js

Okay, read all the updated guides and still cannot figure out why my controller actions are not being called from the view. My ember app has a navigation view inserted in application.handlebars like this:

```
{{view App.NavigationView}}
{{outlet}}
```

Navigation controller looks like this:

```
App.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  navAction: function() {
    console.log('navAction');
  }
});
```

Navigation template:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>{{#linkTo "dashboard"}}Dashboard{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li>{{#linkTo "contacts"}}Contacts{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li>{{#linkTo "campaigns"}}Campaigns{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li>{{#linkTo "transactions"}}Transactions{{/linkTo}}</li>
  <li><a {{action "navAction"}}>navAction</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first mistake is to use `{{view App.NavigationView}}` because the NavigationController is not injected into it.

try to use the new {{render}} helper, like {{render navigation}}. It will lookup both NavigationView, NavigationController, the template 'navigation' and should be wired all together.

Then, the {{action}} helper now acts as explained in the documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Here is a short example, (just miss the use of {{render}} http://jsfiddle.net/JLHuG/40/

Here I defined the action in the current route, but if you define it in the controller (uncomment it), this will be handled by the controller

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at the following post:
[{{action}} with a click event doesn't trigger the function in the v2 Ember router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129444/action-with-a-click-event-doesnt-trigger-the-function-in-the-v2-ember-route)

It talks about using a new helper called {{linkTo}}

Answer (score 0):

Specify the target option in  {{action}} helper to tell, which object should receive the method call. For example:

> {{action "navAction" target="controller"}}

If the target option is unspecified , then it will point to controller.target property which is usually set to the router.  However, the target can be set to the controller itself like this;

> App.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
>
> ```
>        init : function(){
>         this._super();
>         this.set("target", this);
>   },
>
> navAction: function() {
> console.log('navAction');
> ```
>
> } });

You can  refer the following gist  which clearly explains about {{action}} helper in depth:
https://gist.github.com/3595069

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; unfortunately, setting the target in init did not work. I'm using the latest builds if that's of any consequence.

Comment: Hum, I'm pretty sure that now, the default action's target is the controller... if it does not work, this should be a bug